# img2pdf for Python 3.9.1 installation error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, python-3.9, img2pdf

I am trying to execute a python script that needs img2pdf module.

Note, I already have the Ubuntu package installed for python-img2pdf:

```
which img2pdf
/usr/bin/img2pdf
```

Given the following line:

`import img2pdf`

I get the following:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'img2pdf'`

I had only python3.6 version installed before and I have installed python3.9.1 now, After that, I have started getting this error. I think it is something to do with PATH or python default version but after a lot of efforts, I am unable to rectify it.

These are my system details which might help you understand my problem further.

```
$python -V
Python 3.6.9
$python3 -V
Python 3.9.1
$pip -V
pip 21.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
$which python
/usr/bin/python
$which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
$which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip


Ubuntu 18.04.4
Arm64 arch
```

Comment: How did you install it? It seems like you installed it in a different copy/version of Python than the one you're running.

Comment: try `pip install img2pdf`, and run your .py file with python3

Comment: @RandomDavis Yeah thanks that might be the problem as my img2pdf was installed when my python version was older.

Comment: @Sinakzlca I tried this but I am getting this error : ERROR: Failed building wheel for pikepdf
Failed to build pikepdf
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pikepdf which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly..

Comment: @VanshikaShukla did you google that error? I see plenty of potential solutions but you didn't specify that you tried any of those.

Comment: @RandomDavis I tried them but could not find any solution working for me so I used the kaleido package which basically helped me to create pdf from image using writeimage() ..Thank you anyways !!

Comment: @VanshikaShukla I solved that download problem by doing brew install qpdf. It seems there's an underlying dependency file that's generating by installing qpdf

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this, I think img2pdf is a shell cmd and cannot be used as a python module ^^

Best regards

deleaf

```
import os
img2pdf = os.system("img2pdf /path/to/your/image")
```

https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-python/

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but this didn't work in my case :( But I tried to install img2pdf after installing latest pip and then I am getting this error: ERROR: Failed building wheel for pikepdf
Failed to build pikepdf
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pikepdf which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: Incorrect. If you look at the [img2pdf PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/) it says right there: `The package can also be used as a library`